# Prove that there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $p|(n^n-7^p)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Fix an arbitrary prime $p \in \Bbb N$. Prove that there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $p|(n^n-7^p)$

Clearly if $p=7$, can choose $n=7$

For $p=2$, any odd number would work for $n$, but for a general prime, how to proceed? I would like to state that I have been working on a problem and this is where I could reduce it.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: First step would be to reduce $7^p$ modulo $p$. For the rest of the problem, considering primitive roots would help.

Comment: @player3236 Yeah, $7^p \equiv 7 \mod p$ and I know the solutions to $x^n-1$ (as you mentioned primitive roots), but how to proceed in this case? Can you give further hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g$ be a primitive root $\pmod p$, with $g^i\equiv 7\pmod p$.

It suffices to solve $$n\equiv g\pmod p \quad \&\quad n\equiv i\pmod {p-1}$$

As $\gcd(p,p-1)=1$ there is always a solution.

Note:  if you prefer, you can skip the primitive root part and simply solve
$$n\equiv 7\pmod p \quad \&\quad n\equiv p\equiv 1\pmod {p-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that by Fermat's little theorem, $7^p \equiv 7 \mod p$. 
Assume $p \neq 7,2$ Therefore we want to prove that there exists a solution to $n^n \equiv 7 \mod p$. 
 Take $n = (2p-6)(p-1) + 1 \rightarrow n \equiv 7 \mod p$ so $n$ is not divisible by $p$. 
 By Fermat's little theorem $n^{p-1} \equiv 1$ (mod $p$) So we get:
$$n^n \equiv 7^n \equiv 7 \cdot (7^{(p-1)})^{2p-6} \equiv7 \mod p $$
As desired.

Answer (score 0):

We will try to find $n$ of the form $n=mp+7$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$. Then, $n^n=(mp+7)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}m^kp^k7^{n-k}$. The last term here is $7^n$, while all the others are divisible by $p$. So:

$$n^n-7^p\equiv 7^n-7^p\pmod{p}$$

Now, $7^n=7^{mp+7}-7^p$. Assuming $p\ne 7$, we have $7^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, so we are looking for $m$ such that $p-1\mid mp+7-p$. This is possible as $p$ is coprime with $p-1$.